# How to manage Build configuration and Provisioning Profile per Scheme

Tags: xcode, profile, code-signing, provisioning

How do I manage three provisioning profiles in my build schemes?
I am confused because of the fact that there are 2 options per scheme, i.e. Debug and Release.
If I have a "working" scheme for debugging my app on my iPad connected to my Mac I simply set Debug build and use the Developer Provisioning profile for this.
When I select my Ad-Hoc distribution scheme, I select my Release Build which has the Add-Hoc distribution profile set up so that I can distribute the app to the iPads registered in this profile via our website.
But now I want to attach another provisioning profile, the one for iTunes Store distribution, which should also be a Release build, but the Ad-Hoc Provisioning profile is already assigned to Release, so, to clarify my question:
Is it possible to create another Build configuration, something like "iTunes Release", to which I can assign the iTunes distribution profile.  Or is it somehow possible to use different Provisioning profiles with different schemes.

To make a long story short:
In xCode there is a link between Build - Provisioning Profile - Scheme
Where IMHO there should be a link between Scheme - Build - Provisioning Profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on your project in the project navigator (the panel on the left), then make sure you're on the "Info" tab, you can add a new configuration there.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Wow, I must be getting blind, that was indeed what I was looking for, thanks a lot!